# Como Mostrar ventana emergente asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web, webforms

Buenas Tardes.

Quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando un modal que se ejecute siempre y cuando registre y salga un mensaje de error.

Hasta ahora lo que he logrado que si me registra pero el mensaje de modal no se muestra.

Estoy realizando mi inserción con **sql server** y **asp c#** el mensaje de error es una de mi variables de salida de mi procedimiento.

el codigo "+ message +" : es un variable de salida que en mi procedimiento me indica si esta correto el registro o no se procedio el registro o datos duplicados. el registro ya existe

Este es el código de mi code-behind :

```
cmd.Parameters["@idregistrotarea"].Value = lblidregistrotareas.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@usuario"].Value = lblatendidopor.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@fechaemision"].Value = lblfechareg.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimiento"].Value = TxtFechaPago.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@fechaatendido"].Value = TxtFecha.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@montopagado"].Value = TxtMontoPagado.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@numerorecibo"].Value = txtNumeroRecibo.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@tarea"].Value = dprTarea.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@oficina"].Value = dprAgencia.SelectedValue;
cmd.Parameters["@fechaemisions"].Value = txtFechaEmision.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@comentario"].Value = txtComentario.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimientotarea"].Value = txtfechaoculta.Text;
cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cn.Open();
BtnnoConforme.Enabled = false;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", message, true);
cn.Close();

TxtMontoPagado.Text = "";
txtNumeroRecibo.Text = "";
TxtFecha.Text = "";
                }
}
```

Este es el codigo de mi HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showmodalpopup1() {
       $("#popupdiv").dialog({

           width: 400,
           height: 150,
           autoOpen: true,
           draggable: false,
           resizable: false,
           hide: "slide",
           modal: true,


       });
   };

</script>
```

```
div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta: ¿qué valor tiene `scriptText`, `+message+`?, coloca un punto de interrupción en `cmd.Parameters["@fechacumplimientotarea"].Value = txtfechaoculta.Text;`, cuando llegue al punto de interrupción, presiona F10 para continuar línea por línea durante la depuración y revisa si estás llamando bien al script.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave muchas gracias por comentar si mira cuando ejecute y puse una interrupcion en donde dice message lo pase encima y si esta llenando ese mensaje pero cuando termina se registra pero el mensaje no me llega salir

Comment: Pierro, puedes hacer esta prueba: crea otra función "digamos `function mostrarTexto()` { alert('mensaje de prueba'); }" y modifica tu línea: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", message, true);` para llamar este nuevo método. Yo creo que no estás llamando correctamente a la función del popup; además, aquella función no tiene cómo recibir el mensaje de error "el string".

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave si tiene como jalar en mi html hay un div asi :

div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;">

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave o como podia hacerlo ?.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que el Close de la conexión a BBDD la deberías hacer nada más acabar la consulta, antes del ScriptManager.

```
message = (string)cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;
cn.Close();
```

Al ScriptManager le faltan cosas, no puede pasarle solo el texto.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Show Modal Popup", 'var ElMensaje = "' + message + '";', true);
```

Con esto, habrás conseguido pasar en la variable ElMensaje el texto a tu javascript.
Insertar el contenido de la variable en tu DIV y finalmente abres el Dialog de jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showmodalpopup1() {
       $("#popupdiv").text(ElMensaje);

       $("#popupdiv").dialog({

           width: 400,
           height: 150,
           autoOpen: true,
           draggable: false,
           resizable: false,
           hide: "slide",
           modal: true,


       });
   };

</script>
```